# How to set the content length with node.js request module

Tags: node.js, request, form-data

Here is the code that tries to submit a multipart/form-data according to [documentation](https://github.com/mikeal/request#forms):

```
  var request = require('request');
  var req = request.post('http://echo.httpkit.com',
    function (err, resp, body) {
      console.log(body);
    });
  var form = req.form()
  form.append('name', 'value')
```

The response is:

> 411 Length Required

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the form-data library: https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data

```
npm install form-data
```

Then set your code to something like so:

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var request = require('request');

var form = new FormData();
form.append('name', 'value')
form.submit('http://echo.httpkit.com', function(e, r){
  console.log(e,r)
});
```

Comment: Actually, according to documentation the request module relies on form-data for multipart/form-data. Any reason to include request module in your code?

Comment: There is no reason for it in this code. I forgot to take it out when I was debugging your code :)  However, I could see a reason for keeping it in there if you desired to get the html of another page after you made a post request.

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = request.defaults('headers':{'Content-Length':contentlen} });
var post = r.post(url, function(err, response){});
var form = post.form();
form.append('param1', param1);
form.append('data', fs.createReadStream(pathtofile));
```

here contentlen is int